# How to export grid data into Excel in vaadin 7?

Tags: grid, export-to-excel, vaadin7

I have a grid populated with a `GeneratedPropertyContainer`. Some of the columns of my grid have UI components like `CheckBox` and `Button`. I want to export the textual data of my grid to an Excel sheet. I tried with the Exporter add-on. But the Excel sheet gets generated with no data. Here is my Code.

```
ExcelExporter excelExporter = new ExcelExporter(grid.getContainerDataSource());
excelExporter.setCaption("Export to Excel");
layout.addComponent(excelExporter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve the same by passing the container as a parameter to the method `setContainerToBeExported` instead of passing the container as a parameter to the constructor of `ExcelExporter`.

```
ExcelExporter excelExporter = new ExcelExporter();
excelExporter.setContainerToBeExported(container);
```